# logging out is not working in live server godaddy

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I have written a few lines of code in php that helps a user to logout. It works in localhost but in live server the system doesn't logout the users. Could you please help whats wrong with the code?

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['uid']='';
  $userData='';
  $cookie_name="user";
  $out=session_destroy();
  if($out)
  {
   $url=$base_url.'index.php';

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() - (3600), "/"); 
       // 86400 =      1 day
    echo "<script>window.location='$url'</script>";
  }


?>
```

Comment: Try using `unset($_SESSION['uid'])`. Off topic: why are you using JS to redirect the user?

Comment: Nothing special , i used php but I think it's ok to use any of them.

Comment: In my opinion it's easier to use PHP with `header('')`...

Comment: But what about the cockie??

Comment: Yeah, but I used for testing something.. It's ok to use  any of them I think...

Comment: You've unset the cookie correctly (set it in the past) but maybe `$out` is false and the if statement is not accessed

Comment: if , "if" statement is not accessed then how I am redirected ?? It redirects every time  !

Comment: test the code provided in my answer and tell me what you get in the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your live server:

```
<?php
  // session_start() should be at the to of your file
  session_start();

  $_SESSION['uid'] = '';
  unset($userData);

  $cookie_name = "user";

  if(session_destroy()) {
    $url = $base_url . 'index.php';

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() - (3600), "/");
    unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);

    echo "<script>alert($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])</script>";

    //echo "<script>window.location='$url'</script>";
  }
```

Comment: It worked.. but what was the problem? was it " unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);" that make it works?

Comment: maybe that was the problem... At least we found the solution ;) Did you try without `unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);`?

Comment: Thanks friend!! have a nice time ! :)

Comment: happy to help, see you!